# Pack, but don't make it smaller

Tags: java, swing, pack

I have `JFrame` with `GridBagLayout`. User can resize this window. Also, he can perform some editing actions that change window size. I use `pack(); repaint();` now after such actions. But, actually I shouldn't make window smaller after such operations - only bigger. What I found as solution is

```
    Dimension oldSize = getSize();
    pack();
    Dimension newSize = window.getSize();
    setSize(
            (int) Math.max(newSize.getWidth(), oldSize.getWidth()),
            (int) Math.max(newSize.getHeight(), oldSize.getHeight()));
    repaint();
```

But I don't like this solution at all. Beside ugly code, we set size twice (once by pack and than directly). Is there any other solutions?

Comment: What about `setMinimumSize` before `pack`?

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann , thanks a lot. It was what I need. Please post it as answer.

Comment: Call `validate()` instead of `pack()`.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson , unfortunately it doesn't work as I want.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A simple solution would be to use something like this:

```
frame.setMinimumSize(frame.getSize());
frame.pack();
frame.setMinimumSize(null);
```

This will not allow `pack()` to make the window smaller, only bigger, I think.
By resetting the minimum size to `null` after the `pack()` we avoid preventing the user on resizing it smaller afterwards.

You should not need a `repaint()` at the end, the size changing should trigger a repaint by itself. (Of course, make sure that all these actions happen in the event dispatch thread.)

Comment: On Ubuntu, this causes my form to move 10-20px up (that's wierd).

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution to the one proposed by Paŭlo is the following code:

```
private boolean greater(Dimension left, Dimension right) {
    return left.getHeight() > right.getHeight() || left.getWidth() > right.getWidth();
}

if (greater(window.getPreferredSize(), window.getSize())) {
    window.pack();
}
```

The advantage of this solution is that pack isn't called unless it is necessary, and it avoids a flicker we observed on Linux with Paŭlo's solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the pack() method to do that. Not sure if there's a better way though.